# Can I use the Zend framework without command line access?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Lets say yy only option right now is to work on files from my jump drive that I keep on my keychain. I've got a few computers I can use to code on, but none that I can install anything on or alter in any way. Could I get started and use the 'powerfulness' and functionality of the zend framework by just downloading the files to my jump drive and getting started?

Any guides for such a venture?
Or would this defeat the purpose of using the zend framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ZF before the command line interface was added and there shouldn't be any reason (besides not having a webserver to test/execute code, or and editor such as netbeans, etc etc).

Well, that said, do download the reference guide and the API guide, you will be needing them for guidance too (unless those computers have internet). if they have internet you can always sign up to one of those free webhosting (quite annoying) or if you have a webhost use your webhost's file manager to upload ZF libs and your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use it, as long as you have all the files available. You don't actually need the command line to use the framework, although it does help in setting up file and directories for you (but if you understand the framework, you can do that manually).

No, it doesn't defeat the purpose of the framework. It just makes the command line tool unusable except on a single machine.